# Django auth.models.User isn't authenticated, but exists in the auth database

Tags: django, django-authentication

Here is the example, which should, by my current understandings, work. The code bellow is directly copied from testing in `./manage.py shell`

---

There is a registered user in the auth database:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user_in_database = User.objects.all()[0]
print user_in_database.username     #username
print user_in_database.password     #pass
```

---

Authentification test:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
authenticated_user = authenticate(username = user_in_database.username,
                                  password = user_in_database.password)
type(authenticated_user)   #NoneType
```

It returns None, I would have expected it to return the user from the database. Am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is that `user_in_database.password` isn't the user's password. Instead, it's a hash of the actual password (just print it to check yourself).

Essentially, when you call `authenticate`, you're not using the right password.

As such, [authentication fails, and returns `None`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) (because that's what django returns when you pass incorrect credentials).

Comment: You are right! However, there was also flaw in my initial user creation. The user was created with `save()` instead of with `User.objects.create_user` which resulted in a nonhased representation of `user_in_database.password`